# Index of for loop not iterating correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a for loop that is supposed to iterate a number of times equal to the length of an array. The loop runs the correct number of times, but the index does not properly increment.

I tried manually incrementing i with i = i + 1, but that did not seem to change anything.

```
room = [['x','x','x','x','x'],['x','.','.','.','x'],['x','.','.','.','x'],['x','.','.','.','x'],['x','x','x','x','x']]
entities = []

class Entity:
    def __init__(self, x_pos, y_pos):
        self.x_pos = x_pos
        self.y_pos = y_pos

        self.new_x_pos = x_pos
        self.new_y_pos = y_pos
    def Move(self, x_move, y_move):
        self.new_y_pos = self.y_pos + y_move
        self.new_x_pos = self.x_pos + x_move
        if self.CheckCollision(self) is True:
            print("collision")
        if self.CheckCollision(self) is False:
            self.new_x_pos = self.x_pos
            self.new_y_pos = self.y_pos
    def CheckCollision(self, entity1):
        for i in range(len(entities)-1):
            #this loop here. It runs twice, but the value of i is zero for both iterations
            entity = entities[i]
            print(i)
            if entity1.new_y_pos == entity.y_pos:
                if entity1.new_x_pos == entity.x_pos:
                    return True
                    break
            else:
                return False
calipso = Entity(1, 1)
entities.append(calipso)
joseph = Entity(3,2)
entities.append(joseph)
print(entities)
calipso.Move(1,1)

print(calipso.x_pos, calipso.y_pos, sep=' ')
```

I want i to increment each iteration of the for loop, thus i === 0 for the first iteration and i === 1 for the second iteration. Currently, i === 0 for both iterations and I don't know why.

Comment: Are you sure it's running twice?

Comment: why do you think it runs twice? ranges are right exclusive. `range(1)` will only produce `i=0` and stop afterwards. remove the `-1` from `len(entities)-1`.

Comment: The loop itself is only running once, but you are calling `CheckCollision()` twice because within the method `Move()`, you call `CheckCollision()` twice (the two `if` statements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple things wrong with your `for` loop. First of all, if the `y` positions match but the `x` values don't, nothing will happen. Barring this case, however, the `for` loop will always exit after the first iteration because if the positions coincide, `return True` is called (and by the way, because of the `return True`, you don't need `break` after it). And otherwise, it returns `False`.

So inside `Move`, `CheckCollision` is called twice, once for each `if` statement, which is why `i` is printed twice, `0` both times.

To fix it, you would have to have `CheckCollision` return `False` **outside** the `for` loop, so that it checks ALL the entities to make sure it doesn't collide with anything.

The last thing to consider is that you never check that `entity1` and `entity` don't refer to the same object. There are some cases that would result in an entity colliding with itself! Without completely revising the method itself to be like the other answer, the only option to fix that would be some sort of unique `id` attached to each `entity`, but revising the method (as in the other answer) is DEFINITELY the better option.

Also, stylistically, method names for classes should always start with a lower case letter (so your methods should be `move`, `checkCollision`, etc.).

**EDIT:** In this specific case, `i` will never go to `1` anyway. This is because `len(entities)` is `2`, so the `for` loop will go from `0` to `1`, NOT including the end, so no matter what it will stop after the first iteration. But if you had more entities, you would run into the problem described above.

Comment: thank you so much. I fixed the code as you suggested.

Comment: Be aware, the code change suggestions in this answer will check for collision with itself, which will always be true. You need to make sure within checkCollision() that you iterate through every entity but skip the `self` entity.

Comment: @Endyd I actually believe it already takes measures to prevent that. in `Move`, it updates `new_x_pos` and `new_y_pos`, and doesn't set `y_pos` and `x_pos`  until AFTER it checks collision. Because it calls `CheckCollision` with `self`, `entity1` is actually `self` the whole time, and so no collisoin will occur.

Comment: @JohnC.Jameson I'm glad that my suggestions helped you, but Endyd's answer is DEFINITELY better and more idiomatic code. I would definitely take their changes into account.

Comment: @CalvinGodfrey, yes `entity1` will always be `self`, but `entity` within the for loop can also be `self` if OP fixes the `range()` issue. And then if `Move(0,0)` is called on an entity, its `x_pos` will equal `new_x_pos` and `y_pos` will also equal its own `new_y_pos` and cause a collision even though a 0,0 move should not cause any collisions. Also, the method should do what it is meant to do, which, I assume, is to check for collisions against other entities.

Comment: @Endyd Ah true, I didn't consider the case of `Move(0,0)`. I'll add that to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've refactored your code so that the checkCollision method works the way I think you meant it. See comments within the code. I changed the name of the methods to start with lower case.

```
class Entity:
    def __init__(self, x_pos, y_pos):
        self.x_pos = x_pos
        self.y_pos = y_pos
        self.new_x_pos = x_pos
        self.new_y_pos = y_pos

    def move(self, x_move, y_move):
        self.new_x_pos = self.x_pos + x_move
        self.new_y_pos = self.y_pos + y_move
        if self.checkCollision() is True:
            # We don't update x_pos and y_pos here since collision means entity shouldn't move
            print("collision")
            return False
        else: # You need to use ELSE here so that you don't end up calling checkCollision twice
            # if checkCollision returned a False, then we can update the position of entity
            self.x_pos = self.new_x_pos
            self.y_pos = self.new_y_pos
            return True

    def checkCollision(self):
        for entity in entities:
            # Iterate through every entity other than self and see if their position is the same as self's possible new position
            if entity != self and entity.x_pos == self.new_x_pos and entity.y_pos == self.new_y_pos:
                return True
        # Return false if no collision occurs after checking through every entity     
        return False

calipso = Entity(1, 1)
entities.append(calipso)
joseph = Entity(3,2)
entities.append(joseph)

calipso.move(1,1) # successful move
print(calipso.x_pos, calipso.y_pos, sep=' ') # prints 2 2 after succesful move
calipso.move(1,0) # collision with joseph, fails
print(calipso.x_pos, calipso.y_pos, sep=' ') # prints 2 2, calipso did not move
```